# Search and Edit a file in C++

Tags: c++

Good Day to All, I am making a database project for my C++ subject, and I want to ask help about how to edit or replace a file in C++. I cant find a simpliest program that can edit or replace an item in my created file.

Text.txt:

```
name: John Rodriguez

age:12

name: Edward Bantatua

age:15

name: Hemerson Fortunato

age:18
```

In the example I want to edit Hemerson Fortunato and change his name and age. Can anyone help me to make a program for it?, Big Advance Thanks to anyone who help me. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Start with http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ It shows the standard library methods for working with streams/files.

Answer (score 6):

Read the content of your file into string and use `replace()`. Then write the string back to the file. Something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostringstream text;
    ifstream in_file("Text.txt");

    text << in_file.rdbuf();
    string str = text.str();
    string str_search = "Fortunato";
    string str_replace = "NotFortunato";
    size_t pos = str.find(str_search);
    str.replace(pos, string(str_search).length(), str_replace);
    in_file.close();

    ofstream out_file("Text.txt");
    out_file << str;     
}
```

Use `regex_replace` (C++11) or `boost:regex` for more advanced find & replace operations.

Comment: str.find("Fortunato") is fix am i right? what if something like this:

in display:

enter word to find: Hemerson
Record Found!

name: Hemerson Fortunato
age: 18

edit file? Y

enter new name: Jeremy Renner
enter new age: 35
new name and new age save!.


i want output like that but i cannot translate it in code. im always good at thinking a logic like that, but when translating sometimes its get harder. please help.

Comment: @user2803376, use `string name; std:cin >> name;` to enter a name from standard input

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there are mainly two different ways with file operations.
 One is using Fstream functions, that is mainly used in Turbo C and the other one is FILE as a data type.

Now what you can do is create a file pointer.

```
fstream fp;
fp.open("Your_file_path.txt","w");
```

The above code will help you to open ur file.
Next you need to get this file in a string or a char array.
For that you can use the get() function.
To get it, you can add this

```
yourarray=fp.get();
```

in a loop till (EOF) which means the end of file also called as \0.
Now you have all the contents of ur file copied into a char array. All u need to do is search the array for what u want, edit it and replace the entire file contents with the char array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is edit mode program

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
FILE*fp1, *fp2;
char fname[100],lname[100];
char fncomp[100],lncomp[100];
int age; 
fp1 = fopen("OriginalTextFile.txt","r"){
}
fp2 = fopen("TemporaryTextFile.txt","w"){
}
printf("Enter First name of a person that you want to edit: ");
scanf("%s", &fncomp);

while(!feof(fp1)){
fscanf(fp1,"%s %s %d", fname,lname,age);
if(strcmpi(fncomp,fname)==0)
printf("%s %s %d\n\n", fname,lname,age);

printf("Replace name with: ");
scanf("%s %s",&repfname, &replname);

fname = repfname;
lname = replname;

fprintf(fp2,"%s %s %d", fname,lname,age);
}
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);

fp2 = fopen("TemporaryTextFile.txt","r"){
}
fp1 = fopen("OriginalTextFile.txt","w"){
}
while(!feof(fp2))
{
fscanf(fp2,"%s %s %d", fname,lname,age);
fprintf(fp1,"%s %s %d", fname,lname,age);
}
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);

getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

 std::string str_find = "blablabla";
 std::string str_replace = "nonono";

 std::ifstream filein("C:\\Users\\myfilein.txt");
 ofstream fileout("C:\\Users\\myfileout.txt");




 if ( filein )
 {
      std::stringstream buffer;
      buffer << file.rdbuf();
      filein.close();
      // Create a string variable to apply boost::regex
      std::string readText;
      readText = buffer.str();
      // Regular expression finding comments
      boost::regex re_comment(str_find);
      // Replace via regex replace
      std::string result = boost::regex_replace(readText, re_comment, str_replace);
      ofstream out_file(fileout);
      out_file << result;
  }
```

Create your file ".txt" with any text and the expression "blablabla" inside it. This will be replaced by "nonono".

Answer (score 0):

```
void fileEdit(string filename, string search, string replace)
{
        ostringstream text;
        ifstream in_file(filename);

        text << in_file().rdbuf();
        string str = text.str();
        string str_search = search;
        string str_replace = replace;
        size_t pos = str.find(str_search);
        str.replace(pos, string(str_search).length(), str_replace);
        in_file().close();

        ofstream out_file(filename);
        out_file << str;
    
}
```

Use

```
fileEdit("text.txt", "someTextToReplace", "Some more text")
```

on main() and in file text.txt "someTextToReplace" will be replaced whit "some more text".